# iPhone 4 problems dialing from inside app

Tags: iphone, iphone-4, dialing

There is an iOS 5.0+ app, released in App Store, which displays employees profiles with their phone numbers. The users of the app can tap on the phone number and the number will be dialed on their iPhones.

The problem is that some users with **iPhone 4** are reporting that it does NOT dial.

This is the code I am using to dial:

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[self.member.phone componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *urlText = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", escapedPhoneNumber]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlText];
```

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be any `/` in the `tel:` scheme:

```
NSURL *urlText = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", escapedPhoneNumber]];
```

In the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html) you can see some example for what is allowed in the `tel:` scheme.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **telpromt** instead of **tel** this will return you to app after your call ends|

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt:1234567890"]];
```

Comment: Beware that the `telprompt:` scheme is not official and can be removed by Apple in future update of iOS. Also you do not need the `//` in this scheme.

Comment: really? I mean I am using it in almost my all the applications

Comment: Since Apple does not list it as an official URL scheme they can remove it if they want to.